# R: Aggregate dataframe if column has less than 3 zeros, else return zero

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, mean

I have ratings of images by several raters:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(1:6,2),
                               0,2,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0),12,3))
colnames(data) <- c("image", "rater", "rating")
print(data)

#    image rater rating
# 1      1     1      0
# 2      1     2      2
# 3      1     3      1
# 4      1     4      0
# 5      1     5      1
# 6      1     6      0
# 7      2     1      0
# 8      2     2      0
# 9      2     3      3
# 10     2     4      0
# 11     2     5      0
# 12     2     6      0
```

I want to aggregate (`mean`) ratings by images, but only if there less than 3 zero ratings for a given image. Otherwise (=if there are 3 zeros or more), the aggregated rating should be zero. And the counting of zeros should only be for raters 1-5.

So for the above data:

```
#   image   rating
# 1     1      0.8
# 2     2      0.0
```

For image 1 ratings are aggregated because the third zero belongs to rater 6. For image 2, the aggregated rating is zero because there are more than 2 zeros.

On top of that, I want the aggregation to take into account a) only the first 5 ratings for each image, and b) only positive ratings.

I can manage the last 2 conditions using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(rating ~ image, data = data[data$rater <= 5 & data$rating != 0,], mean)

# Result:
#   image   rating
# 1     1 1.333333
# 2     2 3.000000
```

But I can't figure out the first condition.

Correct results should be:

```
#   image   rating
# 1     1 1.333333
# 2     2 0.000000
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Try something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(data)[, if(sum(rating[rater < 6] == 0) > 2) 0 else mean(rating[rating != 0]), by = image]` maybe. Or `library(dplyr) ; data %>% group_by(image) %>% summarise(rating = ifelse(sum(rating[rater < 6] == 0) > 2, 0, mean(rating[rating != 0])))`. whatever vanilla you prefer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg See my answer in the spirit of expanding base R use. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice method using base R:

```
data$this <- ave(data$rating, data$image, 
                 FUN=function(i) if(sum(i[1:5] > 0) > 2) mean(i[1:5]) else 0)
```

I use `i[1:5]` to subset each image, so if you have fewer than 5 raters for an image, you will get an error. This returns the mean for each group, if that is of interest. Of course, you can use the same function to produce the aggregation table you mentioned:

```
aggregate(data$rating, data["image"], 
                     FUN=function(i) if(sum(i[1:5] > 0) > 2) mean(i[1:5]) else 0)
```